# HTTP POST Response code 200 OK

Tags: http, post, get, response

We have exposed a HTTP endpoint with POST method. To make a successful call the clients has to make the POST call with a request body and other required parameters.

When we hit the endpoint directly in the browser the response says 200 OK. Its a GET call. there is no implementation for GET.

The question is - an endpoint which supports only POST should throw an error while hitting directly on the browser with a GET ?

What should be the best error. Do we have to handle this in GET saying GET is not appropriate method on this end point?

Or is it correct to leave the GET response as 200 OK - to make the clients feel the end point is up and running?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about what an HTTP server SHOULD do... the answer is: it *has* to implement GET and HEAD. See RFC 7231.